# Let $F^X$ the linear space of all functions from $X$ to a field $F$, $A \subset X$ then $F^X= N_A \oplus N_{X-A}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F^X$ the linear space of all functions from $X$ to  a field $F$. And also define for $A \subset X$ $$N_{A}= \lbrace f \in F^X \: | \: f(a)=0 \: \mbox{for every} \: a\in A \rbrace$$ and

$$N_{X-A}= \lbrace f \in F^X \: | \: f(a)=0 \: \mbox{for every} \: a\in X-A \rbrace$$.

Of course it is easy to prove that the last subsets of $F^X$ are linear . But I can´t see is that $F^X= N_A \oplus N_{X-A}$. If $f \in N_A \cap N_{X-A}$ then for every $x \in X$ we have that if $x \in A$ then $f(x) =0$, the same if $x \in X-A$ then $f(x) = 0$. Then $f=0$. But what is not so obvious at least for me, is that $F^X= N_A + N_{X-A}$. Thanks for reading and you help.

Comment: Write $f$ as the sum of a function that agrees with $f$ on $A$ and is zero elsewhere, and a function that is $0$ on $A$ and agrees with $f$ elsewhere.

Comment: Not real analysis, not really group theory either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:X \to F$ be arbitrary.  Define $f_A:X \to F$ via $f_A(x)=f(x)$ for $x \in A, f_A(x)=0$ for $x \notin A$.

Similarly, define $f_B: X \to F$ via $f_B(x)=f(x)$ for $x \notin A, f_B(x)=0$ for $x \in A$.

Then $f=f_A+f_B,$ where $f_A \in N_{X \setminus A}, f_B \in N_A$.